# Is there a kibana rest API to get and set default-route of a space?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I need to programmatically retrieve and set default route of a kibana space. On Kibana application, this can be set at **stack management** -> **Advanced Settings** page. I looked at the elasticsearch REST [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.13/api.html), but could not find a suitable API. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what version you are referring to. But the documentation link in the original post points to 7.13. And the suggestion below (from https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-7-5-server-defaultroute-parameter/212191/4) works with 7.13:

> these advanced settings are stored as a Saved Object of type `config`. So you can update them using the [Saved Object APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/saved-objects-api.html)

So here's how I used the API to 'set' and 'retrieve' the defaultRoute in and from my space:

```
$ curl --user elastic:******* -X PUT "localhost:${ES_KB_PORT}/s/${my_space}/api/saved_objects/config/7.13.2" -H "kbn-xsrf: true" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"attributes": {"defaultRoute": "/app/dashboards#/view/285828e0-b713-11eb-aba9-211e5623385d"}}'
{"id":"7.13.2","type":"config","updated_at":"2021-08-02T08:53:19.824Z","version":"WzEzOTksMl0=","namespaces":["mz81"],"attributes":{"defaultRoute":"/app/dashboards#/view/285828e0-b713-11eb-aba9-211e5623385d"}}

$ curl --user elastic:******* -X POST "localhost:${ES_KB_PORT}/s/${my_space}/api/saved_objects/_export" -H "kbn-xsrf: true" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"type": "config"}'
{"attributes":{"buildNum":40943,"defaultRoute":"/app/dashboards#/view/285828e0-b713-11eb-aba9-211e5623385d"},"coreMigrationVersion":"7.13.2","id":"7.13.2","migrationVersion":{"config":"7.13.0"},"references":[],"sort":[1627896123137,107],"type":"config","updated_at":"2021-08-02T09:22:03.137Z","version":"WzE0MDYsMl0="}
{"exportedCount":1,"missingRefCount":0,"missingReferences":[]}
```